# Makefile error: no rule to make target (Solaris -> Linux)

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm porting an app from Solaris to Linux and i'm having problems with this makefile:

```
LIBNAME=Xsa

BASEDIR=../..
include $(BASEDIR)/makefile.Env

SOURCES = \
    ../bdriver/src/BDriver.cpp \
    ../auditor/src/AuditorSQL.cpp \
...

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:../%.cpp=%.o)

INCLUDES = \
...

LIBRARY_PATHS = \
...

LIBRARIES = \
...

.SUFFIXES : .cpp .o

%.o : ../%.cpp
        @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
        @echo "Compiling $< ($(MODE) mode)..."
        @$(COMPILER) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDES) $(ADD_DEFS)
```

Generating the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `bdriver/src/BDriver.o', needed by `../lib/libXsa.so'.  Stop.
```

The folder hierarchy:

```
[dev1@pt086tvr bin]$ ls
makefile.Xsa
[sabsdev1@pt086tvr bin]$ ls -l ../bdriver/src/
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 dev1 bsadm 55060 Nov 29  2012 BDriver.cpp
```

Thanks

Comment: `include $(BASEDIR)/makefile.Env` Acquiring file contents over psychnet. This may take a few minutes.

Comment: The makefile.Env file just defines environment vars for the include sections.

Comment: Does `../bdriver/src/BDriver.cpp` exist? Can you give a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org)?